# Adjust geom_bar plot with large label count

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I want to display [this data](https://pastebin.com/n9EYb9zL) in a `geom_bar()` plot.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
ggplot(fill_names, aes( x = row_mean, y = count/unique(variable) %>% length, fill = variable   ))+
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(),aes(colour=pol_dir),stat = 'identity' )+
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c('Right','Left'),values = c('Red','Blue'))+
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value>0,str_c(round(value*100,2),'%'),'')),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2,col="firebrick", show.legend = T,colour= 'black')+  
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = fill_names$row_mean)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  coord_flip()+
  ylab('Count of users with the same row mean')+
  xlab('Row mean of users')
```

which results in this :[image]

Improvments I'm looking forward to:

**Q1**: How to change the color of `geom_text()`to e.g. black, while `scale_colour_manual()` is already in use?

**Q2**: How can one only display those values of the column `variables` in the bars that share a non-zero value in column `value`?

**Q3**: How can one get some kind of "magnifier" effect above thoses bars with a low amount of counts but a large amount of labels?

Comment: Q3 answer: you could normalize by row so that you get proportion instead of count in the x axis. Optimally you could add a second x axis at the top of your graph, displaying count so that you have both information

Comment: I honestly think you should completely reconsider the way you are presenting your data. Even with your proposed changes, I think this is going to be extremely difficult and unintuitive for a general audience to understand. There are clearer ways to show the same data.

Comment: @AllanCameron could you propose another/better way to display the data?

Comment: @mugdi sure, could you perhaps tell us a bit more about what the data represents? What is "Row mean of users"? Is `count` the number of users with that particular row mean?

Comment: @AllanCameron Well, row mean of users is a confusing terminology, I agree. The original dataset which I'm unable to share represents survey data of questions if a person agreed/disagreed with a specific topic explained by the values of the `variable` column. `-1` if they agreed with a topic/talking point typically considered "Left" and `1` if they agreed with a topic/talking point typically considered 'Right'. Disagreement in both type of questions resulted in a value of `0`. The row mean is the mean of the values from a users survey results. Your description of `count` is correct.

Comment: @AllanCameron are you still on this? Thankful for every hint. Just want to ask if I can provide anything more to create a informative plot!

Comment: @mugdi I have posted an answer with one possible approach. This looks much cleaner and more professional, but I'm not sure if it conveys the message you wanted to display (this isn't totally obvious ftom the info provided)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of the data set, a more aesthetic and legible plot could be something like this:

```r
fill_names %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  mutate(variable = substr(variable, 5, 50),
         value = ifelse(pol_dir == "Left", -value, value)) %>%
  mutate(variable = case_when(
    variable == "abort" ~ "Abortion",
    variable == "anti_racism" ~ "Anti-Racism",
    variable == "climate_change" ~ "Climate Change",
    variable == "feminism" ~ "Feminism",
    variable == "Gender" ~ "Gender Rights",
    variable == "gun" ~ "Gun Rights",
    variable == "left_wing" ~ "Left-wing rights",
    variable == "LGBTQ_Gender" ~ "LGBTQ Gender rights",
    variable == "right_wing" ~ "Right-wing rights")) %>%
  select(-pol_dir) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = row_mean, x = value, fill = value > 0, alpha = count)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(value < 0), orientation = "y") +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(value >= 0), orientation = "y") +
  guides(fill = guide_none(), alpha = guide_none()) +
  facet_wrap(.~variable) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0015BC", "#E9141D")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.35, 0.35), name = "Mean score") +
  labs(title = "Importance of issues according to mean score on all questions",
       subtitle = paste("Bar size shows mean score, density indicates",
                        "number of respondents at each mean score")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.spacing.y = unit(8, "mm"),
        strip.text = element_text(face = 2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.6, 0.6), name = "Views on issue",
                     labels = c("", "Left wing", "", "Right wing", ""))
```

[image]